# Cordova : Can't add new page for my multi-page application

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to cordova. I am try to build a multi page application. After I created the project, it has only one index.html file. I edited the page and made my first page. Now I am confused that how to add my second page in that html file. I created a button I need to go to the new page when I click on the button. 
I am using cordova in my ubuntu system. I am a beginner in programming. Can anyone tell me the solution for my problem? I used cordova+ionic to bulid the page,because I don't know how to create pages using cordova only. I made the page using ionic framework. But don't know how to add new page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">TREASURE HUNT</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
<!--section id="first_page"-->
<div class="list card">
<div class="item item-body">
    <img class="small-image" src="treasurehunt.png" height="200dp" width="fill_parent"><br/>
 
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">                                
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
  </label>
</div>
<a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm" href="#clients">Login
</a></br></br><a href="#">Sign Up</a></div></div></ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you check the ionic documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the Ionic framework. They provide their own [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/) and even [an example of how to create a multi-view app with navigation](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/#).

---

Old answer below:

> Cordova is not too different to using a very simple linux server.
>
> Use a anchor element to link to the second page using relative URL.
>
> ```
> <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm" ref="clients.html">Login</a>
>                                                                        ^
>                                                                        |
>                                                                        notice the .html?
> ```
>
> The biggest thing to remember is that Cordova is a tool to get your HTML/JS/CSS onto a mobile device.
>
> Adding a page to your App is like adding a page to a website.
>
> Create another HTML document and link to it using an anchor tag. You will need to include all the relevant scripts and styles for that page.

Comment: ok. but I don't know where to place the codes of my second page. I found only one index.html file. Should I need to add the code of second page within the index page? Or should I need to create another html file and need to place it in the 'www' folder? @evolutionxbox

Comment: Ok. Got it. I made the clients.html file with the relevent scripts and styles and placed it in the www folder. Then I linked it through the anchor tag. Now it is working. :) @evolutionxbox

Comment: @SANGEETHKUMARSG Glad to know I helped.